# How do you make a shortcut for an excel file?

Tags: excel

I didn't want multiple copies of the same excel file. Hence, the interest in finding the answer. Any kind of help would be nice to have.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS, rightclick on the file and select make alias. Then drag the alias to wherever you want like onto the desktop.

I keep my desktop clear by having 1 folder with all the aliases in - neater than spread over the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a desktop shortcut for an Office program**
If you are using Windows 10 (FYI... I tried in window 11)

1. Click the Windows key, and then browse to the Office program for which you want to create a desktop shortcut.
2. Left-click the name of the program, and drag it onto your desktop.

A shortcut for the program appears on your desktop. Just Drag and drop to the respective folder of interest.

credits: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-desktop-shortcut-for-an-office-program-or-file-9a8df64b-cd87-4700-95cc-4bc3e2a962da